# What is the difference between edge and ridge detection?

Tags: image-processing, edge-detection

The title is tells already enough, but citing [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ridge_detection#Relations_between_edge_detection_and_ridge_detection):

> The purpose of ridge detection is usually to capture the major axis of
>   symmetry of an elongated object,[citation needed] whereas the purpose
>   of edge detection is usually to capture the boundary of the object.
>   However, some literature on edge detection erroneously[citation
>   needed] includes the notion of ridges into the concept of edges, which
>   confuses the situation.

But the difference is still not clear to me. Can you help (eventually with some example)?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Implementing ridge detection](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/585160/implementing-ridge-detection)

Comment: The linked question seeks for an implementation, there is no discussion about the two topics

Comment: See [here](http://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/1714/best-way-of-segmenting-veins-in-leaves) in the answer

Comment: I think that now the difference is clear. If you'll post it as an answer, I'll chose it

Answer (score 12, accepted):

- **Edges**: Borders between areas of high and low gray value.
- **Ridges**: Thin lines darker or brighter than their neighborhood.

Usually, if we do an edge detection on a ridge area we will get a double line, one from each side of the ridge.

[image]

This answer is based on [this answer](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/1714/best-way-of-segmenting-veins-in-leaves), which gives a much more detailed explanation.